# Добавить адаптивного слайдер на адаптивный сайт

Tags: javascript, jquery, адаптивная-верстка

Для сайта был задан свой скрипт адаптивности - вызов функций

```
AddressSwitcher();
fixMobileSafariViewport();
CasesLogo();
```

Затем был добавлен адаптивный слайдер OwlCarusel - http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/ со своей функцией при изменении размеров окна. Проблема в том, что при resize выполняется либо общий скрипт, либо (при отключении общего) скрипт данного слайдера.

В общий адаптивный скрипт была включена функция ResizeSlider()

```
function ResizeSlider() {
    $('.owl-item').each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var widthItem = $(window).width();
    item.css('width', widthItem);
    console.log(widthItem);
    });
}
```

И слайдер стал адаптивным. Проблема возникает при переключении слайдов при изменении размеров экрана - он запоминает старые значения и неверно показывает старые следующие/предыдущие изображения - http://serenity.su/case/sites/dvor1 (первый слайдер). Как это исправить?

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

**Обновление**

Спасибо, оказывается конфликт был здесь:

```
  // If is mobile Safari set window height +60
  if (mobileSafari == 'Safari') {
    // Height + 60px
    $('.newstyle').css('height',(($(window).height()) + 60)+'px');
  } else {
    // Else use the default window height
    $('.newstyle').css({'height':(($(window).height()))+'px'});
  }
```

Хотя браузер использовался не Safari для теста.

Comment: если `AddressSwitcher();fixMobileSafariViewport(); CasesLogo();` убрать, то все ок будет? что в этих функциях? надо понять с чем конфликт

Comment: вы этот скрипт откуда вообще взяли? он нужен вам? удалите все лишнее.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Answer (score 1):

В функции, следующей за ResizeSlider() была неопределенная переменная mobileSafari, соответственно, весь блок, включающий функцию ResizeSlider() и функцию с переменной mobileSafari, не отрабатывал. Помогло выяснить эту ситуацию поэтапное удаление функций.